# reading Javascript object

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following object in JavaScript that I capture from the console window:

```
Object
    action: "android.intent.action.SEND"
    clipItems: Array[1]
    component: "ComponentInfo{com.reunion.family/com.reunion.family.MainActivity}"
    extras: Object
        android.intent.extra.SUBJECT: "Adam Harris"
        android.intent.extra.TEXT: "http://www.adamwadeharris.com/setup-remote-debugging-phonegap/"
        share_screenshot_as_stream: "content://com.android.chrome.FileProvider/images/screenshot/1472164245526-1842859201.jpg"
        __proto__: —
    flags: 318767105
    type: "text/plain"
    __proto__: —
```

I can read the outer fields just find and the clipItems object without a issue. However the extras object I'm having a issue reading the "android.intent.extra.TEXT" and " android.intent.extra.SUBJECT" fields.
 the object  that I wrote out to the console is called: intent

```
console.log(intent);
```

so I tried:

```
intent.android.intent.extra.TEXT
intent.extra.TEXT
```

but keep gettng a error message :

```
Error in Success callbackId: IntentPlugin1397752597 : TypeError: Cannot read property 'intent' of undefined
```

so i must be missing something.

any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `.` to access a property name that isn't a valid identifier. Since the property name contains `.` characters, which are used as delimiters between nested properties, you can't use `.` to access the property itself. You have to use `[]` to access it.

```
intent.extras["android.intent.extra.SUBJECT"]
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `intent.extras["android.intent.extra.SUBJECT"]`?

Comment: It's not clear what the variable `intent` contains. I guessed it was already pointing to the `extras` object, since he didn't use `extras` in any of his tries.

Comment: Oops, now I see that he said that `intent` is the object he wrote to the console.

Comment: @Barmar, Thank you that was it, and thank you for the nice explanation